# WPF MVVM Should CRUD actions have their own views/viewmodels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, crud

Hi I am new to WPF MVVM and have a basic design question:

Should I have separate views and viewmodels for each CRUD action?

Basically I have a datagrid showing a list of Products, from this grid I want to be able to click any of 3 different buttons, each one opening a separate page allowing editing/adding/deleting etc..  Just wondering if I should have each action in its own view?  I come from a WinForms background so naturally went for single view providing all 3 functions but wanted to check the best approach in WPF MVVM.

I have done quite a bit of searching on this subject but as usual I keep finding conflicting information.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can combine Edit/Create (Create/Update). But generally its your service that will have this break down. But basically, you do it how you want, and that is maintainable. If you follow MVVM, do so where it makes sense. You'll soon find out what works and doesn't, shortcuts, the needed long routes.

Comment: You will find that there can be a lot of overlap between an create and an update. I don't use seperate views for those things.